# Generalizing Quines: Outputting an Arbitrary Function of Source Code

Tags: computability, fixed-points

​​A [Quine](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quine) is a (non-empty) program $P$ that takes no inputs and returns its own source code $\langle P\rangle$ as the only output. For a function $f$ (with appropriate domains and range) define an $f$-Quine as a program $P$ that takes an input $x$ and outputs $f(\langle P\rangle, x)$. Thus, with no inputs and when $f = id$ we recover the standard notion.

Given a source code $\langle f\rangle$ for $f$ in some programming language is it possible to efficiently compile it into an $f$-Quine in the same language? I think this would amount to making [Kleene's recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem) very concrete.

Comment: The standard proof of the recursion theorem is perfectly constructive and explicit: let $Q$ be a program that takes as input the code $\langle R\rangle$ of a program with one input, and outputs the code of the program $f(\langle R(\langle R\rangle)\rangle,x)$ (that is, hardwire the input $\langle R\rangle$ into $R$, and hardwire the code of resulting program into $f$). Then put $P=Q(\langle Q\rangle)$.

Comment: Hi there!  When I was a grad student, I implemented something like this for fun and it seems to still work.  It makes self-referential webpages.  If you're interested, see here: http://michaelwehar.com/quines/howto.html  Maybe we could collaborate to make a more refined version of this in the future.  :)

Comment: Here's the program that builds "f-Quines" for you: http://michaelwehar.com/quines/self_reference_made_easy.html

Comment: For more explanation, when you define G(x,y), x refers to the webpage's own source code and y refers to the input that will be put by the user into the generated webpage's textbox.  It then outputs the code for a webpage with the textbox that takes in y as input and evaluates G(e,y) when you click the button where e is the webpage's own source code.

Comment: To better understand, as an example, you could type in "console.log(x);" and click generate.  Then you could create a webpage with the generated code.  This webpage will print its own source code to the console and ignore the input y.